# Create Pull Request on Git Push

Tags: github, github-actions

I have GitHub repository with 2 branches: "master" & "develop".

The workflow for us is that any code should be committed to the "develop" branch then pushed to GitHub, then a Pull Request should be created to merge the commits into the "master" branch.

I am trying to write an Action that will create a Pull Request once a developer pushes commits to the branch "develop" and had the following script:

```
name: Create pull request
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  prForMasterBranch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v2
        with:
          commit-message: update master branch
          title: Update master branch
          branch: develop
```

I can see that this action has executed successfully on "Push" event of the "develop" branch, but I can't see any new Pull Requests!

I checked the logs for the action and found these lines at the end of pull request creation:

> Pushing pull request branch to 'origin/develop'
>   Branch 'develop' no longer differs from base branch 'master'
>   Closing pull request and deleting branch 'develop'

It seems I am missing something, but couldn't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/blob/master/docs/examples.md#keep-a-branch-up-to-date-with-another

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but if I remove the "with: ref: master", so how the create pull request will know to which branch I need to merge the "develop" branch with? I mean I think we should mention the "master" branch somewhere, right?

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/blob/master/README.md) of the create-pull-request action, it mentions that

> Create Pull Request action will:

> - Check for repository changes in the Actions workspace. This includes:
>
>   - untracked (new) files
>     - tracked (modified) files
>     - commits made during the workflow that have not been pushed
> - Commit all changes to a new branch,
>   or update an existing pull request branch.
> - Create a pull request to
>   merge the new branch into the base—the branch checked out in the
>   workflow.

It would always need an intermediary branch where it can commit the changes.

So if you modify your workflow config as below, adding the `Reset master branch` step to get the latest changes from the remote `develop` branch and reset the `master` branch, and specify `branch: temp` for the action, the workflow would create a `temp` branch with the same commits that you have pushed to `develop` branch and open a PR from `temp` to `master` branch. In subsequent commits to develop, it would keep on making the same changes to `temp` branch and open a PR similarly or update the existing PR.

```
name: Create pull request
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  prForMasterBranch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - name: Reset master branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin develop:develop
          git reset --hard develop
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          commit-message: update master branch
          title: Update master branch
          branch: temp
          delete-branch: true
          assignees: user-you-want-to
          reviewers: user-you-want-to
```

Note that the `temp` branch will have the exact commits that are pushed to the `develop` branch.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: @user13602154 why is a temp branch required? why cant we directly create the PR from develop to master?

Comment: That's the same question. Did you find anyways to do it without any intermediate branch?

Answer (score 2):

**PR without intermediate branch**

Replace

> team-you-want-to

or

> user-you-want-to

with team or user you want assign if needed, if not comment them.

```
name: Create pull request
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  reatePullRequest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: master
      - name: Get latest changes
        run: |
          git fetch origin develop:develop
          git reset --hard develop
      - name: Create Pull Request
        id: cpr
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          commit-message: Update master
          committer: GitHub <noreply@github.com>
          author: ${{ github.actor }} <${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com>
          signoff: false
          branch: develop
          title: 'Updating master'
          labels: |
            update
          reviewers: user-you-want-to
          team-reviewers: |
            team-you-want-to
          draft: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the **git fetch** lines, they solved my automation workflow for PR's.