# Create Pull Requests Automatically

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to create a PR for code review that compares the **master** branch (base) with the **dev** branch, whenever someone make a push to dev branch and i want to assign a reviewer to this PR.

I know this can be achieved by Github Actions and workflow and i have written a yaml file for that too as shown below:

```
name: Create Pull Request
on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
jobs:
  createPullRequest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create Pull Request
        id: cpr
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v2.8.0
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          commit-message: Just a test of PR
          title: 'Test PR for github action'
          labels: automated pr
          assignees: assignee1
          reviewers: reviewer1, reviewer2
          draft: false
          base: master
          branch: dev
```

When i run this workflow i get the following log:

```
Pull request branch to create or update set to 'create-pull-request/patch'
Configured git committer as 'GitHub <noreply@github.com>'
Configured git author as 'github-actions[bot] <41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com>'
Rebasing commits made to branch 'dev' on to base branch 'master'
Pull request branch 'create-pull-request/patch' does not exist yet
Branch 'create-pull-request/patch' is not ahead of base 'master' and will not be created
```

No PR is created but the Github Actions workflow runs successfully.
Solution to this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172994/create-pull-request-on-git-push/62180111#62180111) of mine and update your action config accordingly

Comment: did that help sort out your problem?