# Create a PR from feature to master automatically without creating a temp branch

Tags: github, automation, continuous-integration, github-actions

I looking to create an automation workflow where in for each new feature branch, a pull request is automatically created on push, with the base branch being `master`.

Example :

Let's say I create a new feature branch `feature/123` on pushing the branch with commits to Github, I want a PR to be created with the `master` as the base branch (If it does not exist already).

How can I achieve this ?

I did checkout [Create Pull Request on Git Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172994/create-pull-request-on-git-push) this thread. But this there anyway to do this without the intermediate branch.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72728641/17769815) answer seems to do what you want.