# Why am I pushing to one repository but the Pull Request is created in another?

Tags: git, github, push, pull-request, git-push

I am working on this public repository called [tallyfor/flow](https://github.com/tallyfor/flow). As
you see, it is a fork of
[nodename/flow](https://github.com/nodename/flow) which in turn is a
fork of the original [fmnoise/flow](https://github.com/fmnoise/flow).

Locally, I created a branch called
`add-ci-to-automatically-publish-packages` and added a `ci.yml` file
(Continuous Integration effort).

After executing the command below to create a Pull Request:

```bash
git push origin add-ci-to-automatically-publish-packages
```

Things seemed to be correct about the "address" where the Push would go:

```bash
~/projects/flow on add-ci-to-automatically-publish-packages
➜  git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:tallyfor/flow.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:tallyfor/flow.git (push)
```

However, something weird happens, since my Pull Request **does not**
go to the expected repository. Instead of going to
[tallyfow/flow](https://github.com/tallyfor/flow/pulls), the Pull
Request goes to [nodename/flow](https://github.com/nodename/flow) - see the [PR here](https://github.com/nodename/flow/pulls).

Why does this happen? How can I make the changes on tallyfor/flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer (which makes no sense without the background)

It seems likely that you're using one of the automated setups, where you (or someone you work with) has set things up so that your `git push` to your fork triggers a GitHub Action that creates a PR from your fork to its upstream.  That's not something *Git* does, that's something Git*Hub* is doing.  If you don't want it to do that, stop telling it to do that.

#### Background

The `git push` command does not, in and of itself, create a pull request.  It literally *can't*, as Git knows nothing about pull requests.  Pull requests are a *GitHub* feature, not a *Git* feature.

If you so desire, you *can* set up a GitHub repository so that pushing to particular branch names automatically creates a pull request.  This does not happen because of the `git push` itself but rather because of a *GitHub Action* that *you install*.  For further information about this, see [Create Pull Request on Git Push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62172994/1256452).

When you create a GitHub Pull Request using the GitHub web interface or the [github-cli](/questions/tagged/github-cli) `gh` command, *you choose* where the PR goes.  If you've forked a fork, the *default* is for your PR to go to the fork you forked, not the original fork.  To redirect the GitHub PR elsewhere you must use GitHub's "compare across forks" option, [as described on the GitHub help pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork).

I'm sure it's possible to combine these, so that a push to a fork of a fork can automatically create a PR to the original repository.  I think this is what is happening here.

Comment: You are correct. The answer was commenting out the .circle-ci/config.yml file.